# Forcing drawingContext lines to snap to pixel boundaries

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm drawing a graph in a WPF application, but lines drawn using `drawingContext.DrawLine(...)` are drawn to sub-pixel boundaries.

I'm able to get them to look nice by creating `Line` objects, but I don't want to create tens of thousands of those every time the visual is invalidated.

How can I force them to fit to pixels?

Comment: good question, a question on my part, and I hope I understand you correctly, so you chose to draw a graph, doing everything (every line) yourself - super impressive, my head's down. Now do you need to? is it possible for you to use a library to do the heavy lifting for you? ..unless of course, you are writing your own charting component.

Comment: @denismorozov it's my own charting component. I'm graphing page references from a simulated memory manager for a school project. We're investigating how the memory operations of different algorithms go through phases, and trying different page replacement algorithms to minimize page faults. It's really fun :)

Comment: very cool! I am thinking about play with my own charting control too. Good luck!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may draw the lines into a derived DrawingVisual that has the protected [VisualEdgeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualedgemode.aspx) property set to `EdgeMode.Aliased`:

```
public class MyDrawingVisual : DrawingVisual
{
    public MyDrawingVisual()
    {
        VisualEdgeMode = EdgeMode.Aliased;
    }
}

public class DrawingComponent : FrameworkElement
{
    private DrawingVisual visual = new MyDrawingVisual();

    public DrawingComponent()
    {
        AddVisualChild(visual);

        using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
        {
            dc.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1d), new Point(100, 100), new Point(100, 200));
            dc.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1d), new Point(105.5, 100), new Point(105.5, 200));
            dc.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1d), new Point(112, 100), new Point(112, 200));
        }
    }

    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return visual;
    }
}
```

Strange enough, but calling `RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(visual, EdgeMode.Aliased)` on a non-derived  DrawingVisual doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 2):

That's great.

Another option (more complicated in that case) is using RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode on a DrawingGroup:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16984921/2463642

Comment: Worked fine from me, thanks. Icons are no more blurry now